# .strip() not working on my tuple (python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tuples, linear-regression

My linear regression outputs a tuple with extra spaces.

This is the tuple:

```
[[ 1.68307022e-06 -6.37252930e-03  3.34342307e-04  5.77858704e-02]]
```

It has a leading space and some double spaces

This is the `str()` form of the tuple:

```
[ 1.68307022e-06 -6.37252930e-03  3.34342307e-04  5.77858704e-02]
```

NOTE: The tuple has a single value which is 4 numbers separated by spaces

The following code fails to strip() the tuple

**My code:**

```
coef = str(model.coef_[0]).strip()
each_coef = coef.split(" ")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is it outputting a string in some arbitrary format, instead of an actual tuple/list/whatever?

Comment: That is not the representation of a tuple. Can you print model.coef_[0] and show what it actually looks like. Also print(type(model.coef_[0])) would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

**Just a thought**

> Why cast it to string and then use it?

**You can directly access all 4 variables**

```
coef= model.coef_[0]
for each_coef in coef:
    print(each_coef)
```

Or even use as such

```
coef1, coef2, coef3, coef4 = model.coef_[0]
print(coef1, coef2, coef3, coef4)
```

But if you insist, Using regex extraction for extracting from strings

```
import re

coef = "[ 1.68307022e-06 -6.37252930e-03  3.34342307e-04  5.77858704e-02]"

# search for all types of int, float and scientific notation
formats = re.findall("([+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+))([eE][+-]?\d+)?)", coef)

print([x[0] for x in formats])
```

Comment: I gave you +1 because this was what I was going to say in my comment as well. But this does not answer the OP's question. Please provide a solution for the strip() version as well along with this suggestion.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen on it. :)

Comment: I appreciate this method. Much quicker, thank you very much!
I can't +1 yet because of reputation, but well deserved!

Comment: That's alright @PHGLPagani, Happy Coding!